# Conditional asignment with yield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm working in a react, redux, sagas project and in the saga file I have all the generators. Inside one generator I want to asign a variable like this:

```
const test = obj?.test || yield call("other generator")
```

But I can't do this because i got the following error:

```
"Parsing error: Can not use 'yield' as identifier inside a generator".
```

I don't understand why. Can someone tell me why it's not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do like this:

```js
    const test = yield obj?.test || call("other generator")
```